# When does __getattr__ get triggered?

Tags: python

I have a class as follows:

```py
class Lz:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self.b.__getattribute__(item)
```

And I create an instance and print :

```
a = Lz('abc')
print(a)
```

Result is: `abc`

I have set a breakpoint at line `return self.b.__getattribute__(item)`, `item` show `__str__`

I don't know why it calls `__getattr__`, and `item` is `__str__` when I access the instance.

Comment: Python 2, right? You should really use new-style classes, and/or migrate to Python 3 already.

Comment: Have you checked [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)?

Comment: @user2357112 I change to `class Lz(object):` it return a object

Comment: @user2357112 yes I use python 2

Answer (score 0):

`print` calls `__str__` (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr) for details), but as `Lz` does not have a `__str__` method, a lookup for an attribute named '`__str__`' takes place using `__getattr__`.

So if you add a [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method, `__getattr__` should not be called anymore when printing objects of the `Lz` class.

Answer (score 0):

`print(obj)` invokes `str(obj)` (to get a printable representation), which in turn tries to invokes `obj.__str__()` (and fallback to something else if this fails, but that's not the point here).

You defined `Lz` as an old-style class, so it's doesn't by default have a `__str__` method (new-style classes inherit this from `object`), but you defined a `__getattr__()` method, so this is what gets invoked in the end (`__getattr__()` is the last thing the attribute lookup will invoke when everything else has failed).

NB: in case you don't already know, since everything in Python is an object - include classes, functions, methods etc - Python doesn't make difference between "data" attributes and  "method" attributes - those are all attributes, period.

NB2: directly accessing `__magic__` names is considered bad practice. Those names are implementation support for operators or operator-like generic functions (ie `len()`, `type` etc), and you are supposed to use the operator or generic function instead. IOW, this:

```
return self.b.__getattribute__(item)
```

should be written as

```
return getattr(self.b, item)
```

(`getattr()` is the generic function version of the "dot" attribute lookup operator (`.`))